# Is is possible to use variable in dialog prompt in LUIS?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

In LUIS if you require some parameters for an action, and add a prompt question, if the parameter is missing, it will send the prompt as a dialog option in the answer.

In my case I have 2 required parameters, and if the 2nd one is missing (the quantity) I'd like the prompt asking for clarification to use the value of the other parameter's value.

For example:

- query: I would like to buy tickets to toronto.
- dialog prompt should
  be: How many tickets to toronto?

I tried setting the prompt to something like "how many tickets to {location}" but obviously this doesn't work.
I haven't found any information on this so I think it's just not possible but I'd like confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible out of the box. However, I believe it could be done if you start overriding things here and there.

The main problem is that the [LuisActionDialog](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/LuisDialog.cs#L286) (the dialog that prompts for parameters) is not receiving the original [LuisResult](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Luis/Models/LuisResult.cs) model (which makes sense since it's not serializable).

So, I think that to start looking into this, you will have to:

1. Override the [MessageReceived](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/LuisDialog.cs#L199) method from the [LuisDialog](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/LuisDialog.cs#L143) class, in order [to create a new dialog](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/LuisDialog.cs#L221) that handles the parameters. Please note that  overriding the [MakeLuisActionDialog](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/LuisDialog.cs#L269) method won't be enough, per what I explained before about not receiving the original LuisResult.
2. Create a new dialog similar to the LuisActionDialog, that will do what the current dialog does but also performs the prompts manipulation that you are looking to have.